# I'm stuck trying to use wp_enqueue and Checking if the toolbar is activated on frontend

Tags: wordpress

I am currently developing a theme and i am having issues when it comes to wp_enqueue. This is what i got but it isn't working.

```
function theme_name_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'style-name',get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/dropdown.css' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_styles' );
```

secondly i am trying to tell if the toolbar is active on the frontend of wordpress or not and using conditions to display something if it is not active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wp_enqueue_script`  is used to enqueue script , use  `wp_enqueue_style` instead

other thing is its better to register script or style first before using

`wp_register_script` // to register script

`wp_register_style` // To register style

then enqueue using `wp_enqueue_script` `wp_enqueue_style` // learn more about it on codex

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_plugin_styles' );

function register_plugin_styles() {
   wp_register_style( 'style-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/dropdown.css' );
   wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name' );
}
```

More info : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style

For the toolbar, maybe you can find something here: http://digwp.com/2011/04/admin-bar-tricks/

Answer (score 0):

There are specific functions to enqueue scripts and styles in wordpress. `wp_enqueue_script` is used to enqueue scripts only and `wp_enque_style` is used to enqueue stylesheets. These enqueued files will be attached at the point where you called the wordpress function `wp_head`. Note that these functions check for MIME type so that if you trying to enqueue a script using the `wp_enqueue_style` then it'll assume your stylesheet as a script and vice versa. You can see the type and explanation of the error if you use a debugger tool. The developers tool in google chrome is quite awsome. You can use this.

There is a function `is_admin_bar_showing` which can tell explicitly whether the admin bar is showing in the front end or not. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin_bar_showing

Comment: Okay but how can i check using an if function do i go if(is_admin_bar_showing == true){ }